# Fitting empirical distribution to theoretical ones with Scipy (Python) with bounds of parameters

Tags: python, parameters, scipy, distribution, bounds

INTRODUCTION: I have a list of 10 numbers. I would like to fit genpareto.

[image]

PROBLEM: model has been math with not provide shape ( green shape). I would like to put bounds on shape parameter during fit. Based on shape parameter the curve get the different effect. From the automated results we get value of shape parameter smaller than zero ( green shape). I am looking a way how to get the red shape of curve. The matched parameter should be interval (0,0.5). The code can be found below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy
import scipy.stats
from scipy.optimize import minimize
column =[17.5, 17.8, 22.4, 22.6 ,25, 25.2, 27.5, 30, 32.4, 32.5]
dist_names = [ 'genpareto' ]
dist = getattr(scipy.stats, dist_names)
def optimizer(objective, x0, args=(), disp=False):
    return minimize(objective, x0, args=(fscale), method = 'TNC',bounds=(0,0.5))
param = dist.fit(column,  floc = min(column), optimizer=optimizer)
```

Is there a way to implement bounds in fit distribution in Scipy?

I would be grateful for any information you can provide.

Comment: [Cross-site duplicate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/549985/6504), though one that [might be permissible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4708/133817).